# Error MySQL when update a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

I have a question:
I have 2 tables in my database:

```
articles:
id  useid  title
users
id  name  surname
```

My view:

```
 Author<select name="author" id="author">
                            <?php foreach ($users as $u): ?>
                                <option value="<?php $u['id'] ?>" <?php if($u['id']==$a['userid']): ?> selected="selected" <?php endif ?> style="width:300px"><?php echo $u['name'] ?> <?php echo $u['surname'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <p><b>Content:</b></p>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" style="width:605px; height: 300px;" rows="200"><?php echo $a['content']; ?></textarea>
```

My Controller:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE articles SET title='$title',userid='$author' WHERE id=$aid" );
```

When I do this I got the error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myblog`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `admindetails` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Help me please guys....

Comment: The error message seems to say *exactly* what the problem is: the updated `articles.userid` does not match any `admindetails.id` value .. the column/relation names seem "odd". (Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: At the start of the question you say your table is called `users`, but your error message indicates `userid` references a table called `admindetails`. Are these two different tables? Is it possible that you have set up the foreign key referencing the wrong table?

Answer (score 2):

```
<option value="<?php $u['id'] ?>" <?php if($u['id']==$a['userid']): ?> selected="selected" <?php endif ?> style="width:300px"><?php echo $u['name'] ?> <?php echo $u['surname'] ?></option>
```

where is your echo statement..

put  `<option value="<?php echo $u['id']; ?>"` instead of  ", Thats why the key is duplicating,every time it will take the same value which is NULL.. 
Just change it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it means that your `$author` variable holds and id(if its a number) that doesn't exist in the `admindetails` table

Comment: User exists with this id

Comment: I make : $author=$this->input->post('author');

Comment: what is the name of your users table? is it "admindetails" ?? as @GarethD mentioned, the foreign key might be wrong if your user table isn't "admindetails"

Comment: I found the error in the option value I had to write <?php echo... ?>
:)